# python code for for mathematics graph

Tags: python

wrote some Python code to plot the coordinates of simple one dimensional linear mapping using matplotlib

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

result = [10]
result[0] = 1
a = 1.1
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)

for i in range(len(result)):
    result[i+1] = a*(result[i] - 1/2) + 1/2
    plt.plot(x, result[i], 'ro')

plt.xlim(0, 10)

plt.ylim(0, 10)

plt.axhline(0, color='b', ls='-', lw=0.5)

plt.axvline(0, color='b', ls='-', lw=0.5)

plt.xlabel(r'$x$', fontsize=18)

plt.ylabel(r'$x_{n+1}$', fontsize=18)

plt.title(r'Graphs of $x_{n+1} = a(x_{n}-\frac{1}{2}) + \frac{1}{2}$', fontsize=20)

plt.show()
```

error message

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    y[i+1] = a*(y[i] - 1/2) + 1/2
    IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about debugging code belong to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

suppose the length of result is $n$, then $i$ in the for loop can attain value $n-1$, then you are accessing the $(n-1)+1=n$-th element of result.

However, in Python, the index starts from $0$ and the last index is $n-1$ but you are trying to acess the $n$-th element, hence that is why you have index out of range.

Comment: remark: you might like to post future such question to stackoverflow rather than MSE.

Comment: Thank you so much. I rewrite "range(len(result)-1)", the error message disappeared. However, any coordinates is entered. Why does that happen? Does that mean that my correction is not there?

Comment: thanks I will try stack overflow  from the next